# Getting a doubly stochastic matrix from a doubly substochastic matrix.

Tags: matrices, convex-hulls

In his lecture notes on Communication Network Analysis ([Link to pdf](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~hajek/Papers/networkanalysisDec06.pdf), pg 52 , line 4), Bruce Hajek writes that

"If $\widetilde{M}$ is a non-negative matrix with all line sums less than or equal to one, then if some entries of $\widetilde{M}$ are increased appropriately, then a doubly stochastic matrix $M$ can be obtained."

By line sums, he refers to row sums or column sums.

I am a bit stuck trying to prove this result. I think I have some idea about why this is correct, but I can't formalize it. I know that $\widetilde{M}$ lies in the interior of the convex hull of all permutation matrices. I need to prove the existence of some direction along which I can move without reducing the value of any element. Then,when we hit the boundary that will give us the required $M$. Is this intuition correct?

I would like to prove this result. I also want to know if there is an actual contruction which performs this so that I can have an algorithm for doing this, or is it that we can only show the existence of such a matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us call an entry $m_{ij}$ a *double slack* (this is a term I coin for convenience; it isn't standard) if both row $i$ and column $j$ have line sums strictly smaller than 1. You may try to prove that:

1. Every double slack has some (strictly positive) room for increment. Hence it is removable if we increase the value of the entry appropriately.
2. The removal of a double slack will not create any new one. If we remove a double slack, the total number of double slacks will strictly decrease.
3. $\widetilde{M}$ has only finitely many double slacks. So, eventually we remove them one by one, all double slacks will be removed in finite steps.
4. $\widetilde{M}$ is doubly stochastic if and only if it has no double slacks. (The "only if" part is trivial. The "if" part is not difficult, but it deserves some explanation.)

Comment: Thank you very much. For proving (4) I think it suffices to show that if $r_i<1$ for some $i$, then there exists $j: c_j<1$, where $r_i$ and $c_j$ represent row and column sums. And this follows from the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^nr_ = \sum_{j=1}^nc_j$.

Comment: @panini Hmm, you don't know that the matrix is doubly stochastic yet, so you can't say $\sum_i r_i=\sum_j c_j$ right away. This needs justification.

Comment: Sorry. Can you tell me if I am missing something. Suppose $\widetilde{M}$ is doubly substochastic, with no double slacks. Let us assume that it is not doubly stochastic. That means there exists either an $r_i$ or $c_j$ strictly less than 1. Let us assume $r_i<1$ for some $i$. This implies that all the $c_j's $ are equal to 1, other wise $m_{ij}$ would be a double slack. Now $\sum_ir_i = \sum_jc_j = \sum_{ij}m_{ij}$, should give us a contradiction.

Comment: @panini You are correct. Please excuse my silly and unnecessary comment.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Birkhoff's theorem and its analog for doubly substochatic matrices. Let A be a DSS matrix, then A can be written as a convex combination of partial permutation matrices. Each partial permutation matrix can be converted to a permutation matrix by adding 1's in proper positions. Convert each partial permutation to a permutation matrix, then you have a DS matrix entrywisely greater than the original DSS matrix.